# Solve the differential equation $y''+4y=g(t)$ using Laplace transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i solve the following differential equation using Laplace Transformation?

$$y'' + 4y = g(t)$$ 
$$Y(0)=0; Y'(0)=0$$
where: 
$$
 g(t) =
\begin{cases} 
0; &  0 \leq t <5  \\ 
(t-5)/5; &  5 \leq t <10 \\
1; &  t \geq 10 \\
\end{cases},
$$

Comment: Did you try anything? You can solve the differential equation in each subinterval and then "glue" the solutions at the endpoints of the intervals. Please show some effort.

Comment: I tried to solve this problem, but without succes.

Comment: Marco, solve these three equations and put them into your post. $$y''+4y=0$$ $$y''+4y=(t-5)/5$$ $$y''+4y=1$$

Comment: Rafa, i need to solve this problem using Laplace Transformation.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You could rewrite $g(t)$ using the Heaviside function $u(t-c)$. Observe we have
\begin{align}
g(t) = \frac{t-5}{5}[u(t-5)-u(t-10)]+u(t-10) = \frac{t-5}{5}u(t-5)+\left( 1-\frac{(t-10)+5}{5}\right)u(t-10)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
(s^2+4)Y(s)=&\ \mathcal{L}\{y''+4y\} =\mathcal{L}\{g(t)\} = \frac{e^{-5s}}{5s^2}-\frac{e^{-10s}}{5s^2} \\
\implies&\ \ Y(s) = \frac{e^{-5s}}{5s^2(s^2+4)}- \frac{e^{-10s}}{5s^2(s^2+4)}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Jacky, but I didn't understand how you get the laplace transformation of $$(t-5)/5 *u(t-5)$$

Comment: I used the fact $\mathcal{L}\{u(t-c)j(t-c)\} = e^{-cs}J(s)$ where $J(s) = \mathcal{L}\{j(t)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, solve these 3 equations \begin{align}y''+4y&=0 \\ y''+4y&=\frac{t-5}{5} \\ y''+4y&=1 \end{align}

with Laplace transformation and then glue the solutions together. $$\mathcal{L}_t\{y''+4y\}(s)=(s^2+4)\mathcal{L}_t\{y\}(s)$$ should be pretty standard, so it remains to calculate $\mathcal{L}_t(0), ~\mathcal{L}_t\{1\}, ~  \mathcal{L}_t\{\frac{t-5}{5}\}.$ Notice that
$$\mathcal{L}_t\{\frac{t-5}{5}\}(s)=\mathcal{L}_t\{\frac{t}{5}-1\}(s)=\frac{1}{5s^2}-\frac{1}{s}=\frac{1-5s}{5s^2}$$

So we get

\begin{align} \mathcal{L}_t\{y\}(s)&=0 \\ \mathcal{L}_t\{y\}(s)&=\frac{1}{s(s^2+4)} \\ \mathcal{L}_t\{y\}(s)&=\frac{1-5s}{5s^2(s^2+4)} \end{align}

Now use partial fraction decomposition and apply the inverse Laplace transform. Keeping in mind that

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t\{\frac{1}{s^2} \}(t)=t, ~\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t\{\frac{1}{s} \}(t)=1, ~\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t\{\frac{1}{s^2+4} \}(t)=\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}, ~\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t\{\frac{s}{s^2+4} \}(t)=\cos(2t) $$

should do the job.